# Append checkbox with conditional checked property

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to append a table with checkboxes, but the checked property needs to be based on another property:

```
$.each(result.scenarios, function (i, scenario) {
    table.append('<tr><td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="' + scenario.Id + '" checked="' + scenario.Shared == true ? 'checked' : '' + '">' + scenario.Name + '</label><br></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: can you add sample of result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checked attribute is a boolean attribute, so you can add the attribute by using this code: `(scenario.Shared ? 'checked' : '')`

```
$.each(result.scenarios, function (i, scenario) {
    table.append('<tr><td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="' + scenario.Id + '" ' + (scenario.Shared ? 'checked' : '') + '>' + scenario.Name + '</label><br></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify any value to the checked attribute. The main difference in my code and yours is that mine doesn't set any value to the checked attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `checked` attribute's value. You need to either put the attribute (without value) or not.

This:

```
checked="' + scenario.Shared == true ? 'checked' : ''
```

would result in all the checkboxes checked. It's because the `checked` attribute is there. The value of the attribute doesn't matter. As long as it's in the HTML when rendered, it will be checked.

Should be:

```
scenario.Shared ? 'checked' : ''
```

No need to assign it to the attribute.

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyKbqm